# Weird GUI behaviour with custom resolver in 'Show items to publish'

Tags: cme, web8, custom-resolver

Anyone seen this weird gui-behaviour with Web 8 and a custom resolver ?

I wrote a custom resolver that, when a category is published, a specific page also gets published (to make life easy for editors).
The resolver works fine - when i publish my category the page also gets published.

But, there's a minor annoyance, when I publish and click 'show items to publish', i get this

[image]

For some reason, the page title is not showing up (it is the correct page though, i verified in the broker which page gets published).

Also, when I debug my custom resolver, I can see the correct page being added to the list of resolved items.

[image]

My code is pretty simple

```
if(item is Category && item.Title.Equals(NAVIGATION_CATEGORY_NAME, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
        Page page = session.GetObject(new TcmUri(NAVIGATION_PAGE_ID, ItemType.Page, item.Id.PublicationId)) as Page;
        Template pageTemplate = session.GetObject(new TcmUri(NAVIGATION_PAGE_TEMPLATE_ID, ItemType.PageTemplate, item.Id.PublicationId)) as PageTemplate;
        resolvedItems.Add(new ResolvedItem(page, pageTemplate));
}
```

Comment: Try to load page after instantiating it:

page.Load(LoadFlags.None);

Your page object has only TCM URI pre-loaded and, the most probably, TCM doesn't force its reload to get title.

Comment: yes, thank you, adding that line of code fixed the problem. The page title is now correctly showing in the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to load page after instantiating it:

```
page.Load(LoadFlags.None);
```

Your page object has only TCM URI pre-loaded and TCM doesn't force its reload to get title.